# How to force overwrite already deployed files in android delphi

Tags: android, delphi, deployment

How to be sure that deployed files will be overwritten in android device?
Regarding:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Deployment_Manager
 you can specify **Overwrite** feature for each file.

**Always:** Deploy the local file if it is **newer** than the remote file, overwriting the remote file

**Never:** Select this option for a file if you want to exclude it from being deployed.
It means, when you **updating** the app, and in destination path, remote file already exists (in mobile device), the file will be NOT overwritten, if it's timestamp is newer.
 Is it possible to force overwrite the newer files on device?
*case study:*
I want to deploy "read only" database within application. In next update, I want to deploy actualized version, so DB file has to be overwritten. But what if database driver changes this file in device? (It is not guaranteed that db file will be not changed, even there will be no insert or update in DB - Probably driver can write some META data...).
What if user will have a wrong time in device (e.g. future years) and therefore "old" file in device will have newer timestamp?

Comment: I feel that files that need to be deployed are files that should not and need not be changed by the application. They are resources like images. If an application changes a file, it does so with intent. The user via the developer wanted it that way. Changing it back through an update causes data loss. As a consequence all files that could be subject to change should not be deployed but generated when used.

Comment: You can copy the startupcopy.pas to your project folder and edit it to allow for overwrites in specific circumstances.

Comment: @nolaspeaker thank you very much, startupcopy.pas is very intersting point where to start.

Comment: The startupcopy.pas is the code the deployment manager actually uses.