# Delete deployed file - Delphi Rio mobile

Tags: delphi, deployment, firemonkey

My Delphi Rio mobile app correctly deploys a sample document file. The user then chooses to delete this file. It is successfully deleted.

Then when the app is next run, the file is deployed again. (confirmed on iOS and Android)

How do I keep my app from deploying that sample file the next time the app is run, after the user has deleted it?

Comment: Related: [How to force overwrite already deployed files in android delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399021/): "*You can copy the startupcopy.pas to your project folder and edit it to allow for overwrites in specific circumstances.*" So, set a flag somewhere when the file is deleted, and then have your modified startup code look at that flag when deciding whether to re-deploy the missing file or not. Otherwise, can't you just generate the initial file dynamically on the first run of the app and not deploy a static file at all?

Comment: To check my understanding, deployed files aren't deployed during installation but rather every time the program starts up?

Answer (score -1):

This questions stems from my incorrect assumption that deployed files were only deployed once, during installation. They are deployed every time the app starts.

To change this behavior, StartupCopy.pas must be modified.

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved with an explanation of what modifications (including sample code) need to be made to StartupCopy.pas and how they specifically solved the problem. The information you've posted as an answer was written by @RemyLebeau in a comment that was just as informative and actually provided more information.